# Querystring query without analysis on es?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field "animal" that is not_analyzed. Is a document with "animal": "fox"
searchable with a querystring query if a user passes in "fo" as the querystring? Or would the user have to pass in "fox" in order to match that document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"fo" won't match "fox" if you're using not_analyzed.

There are three types of index mappings in elasticsearch:

`analyzed` analyses your text and then indexes it. ("fo" matches "fox")
`not_analyzed` indexes your text (makes it searchable) exactly as it is. ("fo" doesn't match "fox", only "fox" does)
`no` the field is not searchable.

[reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html)

Comment: Why is it that when I use a query string query and search on "animal":"fo" it returns nothing? The mapping for the field is the default mapping.

Comment: This happens because the elasticsearch default analyzer only breaks string fields into dictionary words. For "fo" to match "fox" you need to use the nGram tokeniser (or edge nGram) (with n = 2), this breaks "fox" into "fo" and "ox".
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

Answer (score 0):

If you search for fo* it will work , else you need to search for the exact term.